# filter in one group only instead of all

Tags: r, dplyr

I was wondering if there is a way to only filter/exclude inside one group after using the group_by function in `dplyr`. Atm the filter functions is run on all groups, although I only want to exclude certain values inside one group.

Comment: Posts to SO should include reproducible example code.

Answer (score 5):

This keeps only rows for which Petal.Length > 1.5 for the setosa Species and keeps all rows for the other Species.

**1)** `cur_group()` returns a one-row tibble with a column for each grouping variable giving its current value.

```
library(dplyr)

iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  filter(Petal.Length > 1.5 | cur_group()$Species != "setosa") %>%
  ungroup
```

**2)** Within a `group_modify` using a formula argument `.x` refers to the non-group columns and `.y` is similar to `cur_group` in (1).

```
iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  group_modify(
    ~ if (.y$Species == "setosa") filter(.x, Petal.Length > 1.5) else .x
  ) %>%
  ungroup
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe in this case you can formulate it without `group_by()`?

```
iris |> filter(Species != 'setosa' | Petal.Length > 1.5)

# Perhaps clearer:
iris |> filter(!(Species == 'setosa' & Petal.Length <= 1.5))
```

Comment: That is a good point.  In the example I gave it would not be needed but in general it might be needed.  Consider what would happen if one wanted the Petal.Length values that are greater than the mean of the group.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck I agree.